# $\arcsin(\sin(\phi_{\max})\cos(2\pi t))=\phi_{\max}\cos(2\pi t)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I apologize for my ignorance about trigonometry, but I cannot figure out how to derive the identity in the subject that I observed numerically. I also put it here for convenience:
$$\phi(t)=\arcsin(\sin(\phi_{\max})\cos(2\pi t))=\phi_{\max}\cos(2\pi t).$$
where $\phi_{\max}\approx 0.1$. I got rid of $\arcsin$ and did some transformations, but were unable to derive the result. I presume that there is some simple way to treat this problem instead of going to $\exp$-notation etc.

Just for certainty, below is a piece of code:

```
a=469; k=533/1920; T=6.622; d=930; phi_max=asin(a*k/d); 
t=0:0.01:10; 
x=a*cos(2*pi*t/T); 
phi = asin(k*x/d); 
figure(); hold on 
plot(t,phi) 
plot(t,phi_max*cos(2*pi*t/T))
```

Comment: $\arcsin$ is the inverse function of the sine function. That mean that $\arcsin(\sin(\varphi ))=\varphi $ for all $\varphi \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and $\sin(\arcsin(x))=x$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$.

Comment: But there is also $\cos$ _inside_.

Comment: I think it's a typo, it should rather be $$\arcsin(\sin(\varphi ){\color{red})}\cos(2\pi t)$$

Comment: No. It's not a typo. Otherwise it would be trivial.

Comment: Then it's wrong... However, if $\varphi _{max}\ll 1$, then $\sin(\varphi _{max})\approx \varphi _\max$. Moreover $\varphi _{\max}\cos(2\pi t)\ll 1$, and thus $\arcsin(\varphi _{\max}\cos(2\pi t))\approx \varphi _{\max}\cos(2\pi t)$ but you certainly don't have the equality.

Comment: I would also think the same, but when I look at the plot (see the code in the question), I do not see even a tiny discrepancy. This makes me to think that there is something more than just these two functions being approximately equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\phi(t)=\arcsin(\sin(\phi)\cos(2\pi t))=\arcsin(\sin(\phi)T)$$

Using series expansion
$$\phi(t)=T \phi +\frac{T \left(T^2-1\right)}{6}  \phi ^3+O\left(\phi ^5\right)$$

Comment: So, there is nothing special. Just the difference is in the higher term and hence too small to be visible. Thank you!